# Group several Nagios notifications in a single email

Tags: email, nagios

I have a set of passive checks that I update once a week. I want to set up email notifications. I would like that a single email is sent. This email would contain the list of all services in error. Is it possible to configure this in Nagios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nagios doesn't support this, but you might be able to integrate something like [Flapjack.io](http://flapjack.io) to perform rollup alerts.